# cannot select ajax loaded content if I don't include selector inside success function of ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I cannot select any element inserted via ajax call, if jquery select is outside ajax success function. if I move everything under success it works just fine.

can anyone with experience please help me understand what is happening and how to deal with this issue? I'm searching 2 days already can't find anything :S

This works:

```
//Show levels using ajax
//define variables
var levels = 2; //level count can be rewritten to come from DB and not be hardcoded like now
var completed_calls = 0; //count tasks start from 0
var views = new Array();
//All level display ajax function
function create_views(level) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "actions.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: "show_level=" + level,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data){
                views[level] = '<li data-level="' + level + '">' + data + '</li>';

                //Count completed tasks
                completed_calls++;

                //if last level is being called append and activate slider
                if (levels == completed_calls) {
                    //append views to container
                    $(".slides_container").append(views.join(' '));
                    //activate slider
                    var unislider = $(".slides_container").dpUniSlider({
                        //loop: false,
                        draggable: false
                    });

                    //Login and Registration windows on login slide, one closes the other opens up
                    //+ login registration links in header for logged out users
                        //Login
                        $("#header-login, #logwindow").on("click", function(){
                                $("#regsitrationform").hide();
                                $("#register h2").hide();
                            $("#loginform").show().css("opacity",0);
                            unislider.goToSlide(2);
                            $("#loginform, #register h2").delay(480).fadeTo(0, 1);
                                $("#logwindow").removeClass("active").addClass("notactive");
                                $("#regwindow").removeClass("notactive").addClass("active");
                            return false;
                        });

                        //Registration
                        $("#header-register, #regwindow").on("click", function(){
                                $("#loginform").hide();
                                $("#register h2").hide();
                            $("#regsitrationform").show().css("opacity",0);
                            unislider.goToSlide(2);
                            $("#regsitrationform, #register h2").delay(480).fadeTo(0, 1);
                                $("#regwindow").removeClass("active").addClass("notactive");
                                $("#logwindow").removeClass("notactive").addClass("active");
                            return false;
                        });

                        //Pop-up logo tooltip: close
                            $(".close").on("click", function(){
                                $(".logo").fadeTo("slow", 1);
                                $(this).parent().fadeOut("fast");
                                return false;
                            });

                        //Pop-up logo tooltip: clear
                            $(".clear").on("click", function(){
                                $(this).parent().find("input").val("");
                                return false;
                            });

                        //Activate Georgian keyboard for some logos
                            $("input[data-lang=ge]").GeoKBD();
                }
            }
        });
}
//Loop through all levels and display views
for (var i=1; i<=levels; i++) {create_views(i);}
```

This doesn't:

```
//Show levels using ajax
//define variables
var levels = 2; //level count can be rewritten to come from DB and not be hardcoded like now
var completed_calls = 0; //count tasks start from 0
var views = new Array();
//All level display ajax function
function create_views(level) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "actions.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: "show_level=" + level,
            cache: false,
            success: function (data){
                views[level] = '<li data-level="' + level + '">' + data + '</li>';

                //Count completed tasks
                completed_calls++;

                //if last level is being called append and activate slider
                if (levels == completed_calls) {
                    //append views to container
                    $(".slides_container").append(views.join(' '));
                    //activate slider
                    var unislider = $(".slides_container").dpUniSlider({
                        //loop: false,
                        draggable: false
                    });
                }
            }
        });
}
//Loop through all levels and display views
for (var i=1; i<=levels; i++) {create_views(i);}





//Ajax call to display-update single level
function update_view(level) {

}





                    //Login and Registration windows on login slide, one closes the other opens up
                    //+ login registration links in header for logged out users
                        //Login
                        $("#header-login, #logwindow").on("click", function(){
                                $("#regsitrationform").hide();
                                $("#register h2").hide();
                            $("#loginform").show().css("opacity",0);
                            unislider.goToSlide(2);
                            $("#loginform, #register h2").delay(480).fadeTo(0, 1);
                                $("#logwindow").removeClass("active").addClass("notactive");
                                $("#regwindow").removeClass("notactive").addClass("active");
                            return false;
                        });

                        //Registration
                        $("#header-register, #regwindow").on("click", function(){
                                $("#loginform").hide();
                                $("#register h2").hide();
                            $("#regsitrationform").show().css("opacity",0);
                            unislider.goToSlide(2);
                            $("#regsitrationform, #register h2").delay(480).fadeTo(0, 1);
                                $("#regwindow").removeClass("active").addClass("notactive");
                                $("#logwindow").removeClass("notactive").addClass("active");
                            return false;
                        });

                        //Pop-up logo tooltip: close
                            $(".close").on("click", function(){
                                $(".logo").fadeTo("slow", 1);
                                $(this).parent().fadeOut("fast");
                                return false;
                            });

                        //Pop-up logo tooltip: clear
                            $(".clear").on("click", function(){
                                $(this).parent().find("input").val("");
                                return false;
                            });

                        //Activate Georgian keyboard for some logos
                            $("input[data-lang=ge]").GeoKBD();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot select any element inserted via ajax call, if jquery select is outside ajax success function. if I move everything under success it works just fine.

It sounds like the issue is you're trying to bind event handlers to elements that don't yet exist. Try using `on`, `delegate` or `live` (depending on which version of jQuery you're using) on a parent element that's present when your code is executed.

Something like:

```
$(".slides_container").on('click', 'li[data-level]', function () {...});
```

Comment: I have same problem with submit() function, any ideas how to rewrite it?

Comment: Same idea - use event delegation to bind the handler to a parent element that's sure to be there. If the page is blank, use `$('body').on('submit', '.my-form', function () {...})`